# How do I properly use "using namespace foo?"

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am slightly confused by the using namespace x in c++. Why would it be incorrect in this context? Does "using namespace" only applicable to the other files we are #including?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace A;


namespace A {
    void print() {

std::cout << "From namespace A" << std::endl;
    }
}

namespace B {
    void printB() {
        std::cout << "From namespace B" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main() {
    print();
    printB(); 
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @NathanOliver not really the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error messages tell you [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e41c2a993c73e50) these functions aren't declared within your current scope.
everything you call with an unspecified namespace is considered to be found in the global namespace as `::print`, `::printB`.

You need to use the namespace scope operator (`::`) like follows:

```
A::print();
B::printB();
```

or a `using` statement:

```
using A::print;
using B::printB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using namespaces would allow you to have both the functions called print. You would use them as `A::print()` and `B::print()` rather than having to rename one of them `printB()`